# assembly language in function call

Tags: assembly

In this code actually it has coded to save the register values in the function. Is it compulsory to do this always by the function?

[image: code]

Comment: Don't post code as image. No, it's not compulsory, unless you follow a convention that says so.

Comment: It depends. If it is all your own asm code, you decide. If it is called from some compiled code, the compiler's calling convention decides.